# How does javascript know when the response from the backend is ready?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

I am a new to Javascript, so I have some questions about Javascript. I read some articles about event loop and promise/async/await. I know Javascript has a main thread, but I am confused that when Javascript send many requests to backend, how does javascript know when the response from backend is ready? In my option, Javascipt has only one thread so does Javascript use this main thread to check the status of each request over and over again? I don't know what information I should read to solve my doubt. Hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: The backend sends a reply to the client, then the client parses it. That's about it. No polling involved.

Comment: As for the first question, you can know when the response from the backend is ready if already gave a result from the `await`ed function

Comment: The actual request is not done by JS, the request is send by the browser, which can use more threads.

Comment: javascript is said to have a single threaded model of execution - that doesn't mean the engine running the code is single threaded

Comment: @Teemu so you mean that when the browser get the response, then it will notify the JS?

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw  Thanks for your reply. I know I can use the await in my code to get the response. But I am a little confused about how does Js know when this request is resolved?

Comment: Because the server tell the browser: here is the response, it's finished now. Then the browser tells this to the JS.

Comment: Yes. Notice, that when you send a request, you're also attaching an event (or a promise) to the request object (usually `load` or `readystatechange`, a promise when using `fetch`). When the response arrives from the server, the event fires, and you can handle the response data with JS. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/queueMicrotask to better understand the events in general.